# Deploying docker images to autoscaling group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, autoscaling

I simply can't find satisfying answer to how to deploy to autoscaling group in AWS.. I mean classic setup, there is alb, and autoscaling group of EC2 instances. Furthermore, I need to deploy to each 3 docker containers that are in our GitLab repo. I can bootstrap them upon creation with user script that will deploy the latest docker images (but I need to include password/user for log in to docker registry in the script, not a big fun of that). How about updates ? I think I can query the autoscaling group with Ansible to get the up-to-date list of server and use it like that. Or use AWS CodeDeply and push it that way with custom .sh script that would pull and start the images... but yet again I need to include sensitive data inside that .sh script. What else is there ?

The ideal solution would be if I could deploy from GitLab CI/CD and get a list of all servers just by pointing to that group... maybe use Ansible image in a job, build the inventory and run deployment... maybe that could work.

What else is there ? Terraform ( Love that tool, but not sure, it can handle task like that )

Comment: Test terraform, It can handle that. You can use enviroment variable to pass the sensitive information to Terraform. Also you can integrate Terraform with GitLab-CI. In GitLab go to the menu Infrastructure-> Terraform. Also yo can use Terraform Cloud and storage and manage the sensitive data in the cloud.

Comment: Hi @MiguelConde, I'm using Terraform already to deploy the whole AWS infrastructure, but I did not get further than that. Is it possible to have Terraform deploying docker image to autoscale group, without telling it about individual servers ? I mean EC2 autoscalling, avoiding ECS